# Sending user current location to the company?

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-maps, location, coordinates

I want to implement in my application the option to send the current user location with all of his details such as: name, phone number & exact location.
I want all those details to send to the company i'm doing the application for.
Is it possible, for example, that the user will press a button & all those details will be send to the company, & the company could see the current user location on google maps immediately?
Or maybe to send a hyper link with all the details & when clicking on it it will direct you to google maps with the coordinates?
What is the best way to do that?
The application is for emergency purposes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format a Google maps link from a CLLocation instance and send the link:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps/q=%f,%f",[myLocation latitude],[myLocation longitude]];
```